# ConfigurationError: lerc not in acceptable choices for dataset_reader.type

Tags: python, data-science, allennlp, text-analytics-api

we are trying to use the evaluate_rc-lerc pretrained model provided by allennlp in page
https://docs.allennlp.org/models/main/#pre-trained-models
using below colab code

```
!pip install allennlp==1.0.0 allennlp-models==1.0.0
!pip install --pre allennlp-models
!pip install -U nltk

from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
import allennlp_models
# The instance we want to get LERC score for in a JSON format
input_json = {
    'context': 'context string',
    'question': 'question string',
    'reference': 'reference string', 
    'candidate': 'candidate string'
}
# evaluate_rc-lerc - A BERT model that scores candidate answers from 0 to 1.
# Loads an AllenNLP Predictor that wraps our trained model
predictor = Predictor.from_path(
    archive_path='https://storage.googleapis.com/allennlp-public-models/lerc-2020-11-18.tar.gz',
    predictor_name='lerc',
    cuda_device=0
)

output_dict = predictor.predict_json(input_json)
print('Predicted LERC Score:', output_dict['pred_score'])
```

Error:
ConfigurationError: lerc is not a registered name for Model. You probably need to use the --include-package flag to load your custom code. Alternatively, you can specify your choices using fully-qualified paths, e.g. {"model": "my_module.models.MyModel"} in which case they will be automatically imported correctly.

even after using latest packages with pip install allennlp-models==2.2.0

getting the same error. Any working code snippets for 'evaluate_rc-lerc' will be greatly appreciated that directly uses the saved archived to avoid training/finetuning

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the LERC model isn't properly part of `allennlp-models`. It is just part of the demo at http://demo.allennlp.org. I will see if I can get the documentation fixed.

The LERC model is available at https://github.com/anthonywchen/MOCHA. It might not be quite as convenient to use as the other models, but it should still be pretty easy.

Comment: I'm fixing the documentation here: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/pull/320

Answer (score 0):

Extremely sorry but finding using git project https://github.com/anthonywchen/MOCHA quite challenging with packages installation such as version of allennlp torch dependencies, additional packages apart from requirements.txt ,manual data migration,  requires **cuda** capability in internal code and most importantly **the relative folder paths** errors, thus having an archive style pretrained model import of using will help all kinds of users , to avoid dealing with technical errors